# Предупреждение о незаполненной форме

Tags: php, формы

Мое ДЗ в школе заключается в том, чтобы показать сообщение с помощью php, если какое-нибудь поле формы не заполнено. Я вывожу их просто на странице, а мне скзали, что нужно в полях формы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Ниже помещаю то, что я насочинял:

```
foreach ($_POST as $kk => $vv)
{

    echo "POST[".$kk."]=".$vv."<br>\n";

}

if (!$_POST['fname'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Фамилия</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['sname'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Имя</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['mname'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Отчество</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['Day'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: День</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['Month'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Месяц</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['Year'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Год</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['tarea'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Образование</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['pass'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Пароль</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['passd'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Подтвердить</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['sex1'] && !$_POST['sex2'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Пол</span><br>\n";}
if (!$_POST['check1'] && !$_POST['check2'])
{echo "<span class='span1'>Заполните поле: Постоянный клиент или Посетитель читального зала</span><br>\n";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я вывожу их просто на странице, а мне скзали, что нужно в полях формы.

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о коде

```
foreach ($_POST as $kk => $vv)
{
    echo "POST[".$kk."]=".$vv."<br>\n";
}
```

что действительно довольно бессмысленно.

Если форма была заполнена с ошибками, то логично будет заполнить уже введенные данные, чтобы пользователю не пришлось вводить их заново.

Для этого служит атрибут value:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" value="<?=$form['fname']?>">
```

при этом следует помнить, что при первом показе формы все поля массива `$form` должны быть инициализированы пустыми строками. И всегда их содержимое должно быть экранировано, хотя бы с помощью функции `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Извините, я только-только начал учить php. Инициализация пустыми строками и экранирование htmlspecialchars() как будут выглядеть в коде?

Comment: Долго объяснять. Делай так, авось прокатит. Все равно твои учителя знают не сильно больше тебя, и вряд ли заметят эту проблему. А потом, с опытом, сам разберешься.